# Connect to Another system through serial port

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I'm very new to Linux environment and need some help.

I have pc that runs on Ubuntu 22.04. I would like to connect to another system that has a specific IP address, through serial port. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you just want to use the serial port? You would not need an IP-Address then.

Answer (score 0):

The serial port usage is very old and rare nowadays...
But it is possible. There was a PPP (well, still is) but I am not sure it exists in the modern distributions.

Anyway, start reading here: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/